# How can I select label value from client(popup) window?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

In my table I am selecting a text of a label from client window because it has too many options.

Main page:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblText" runat="server">Select Options/asp:Label>
<img onclick="SelectOptions();" src="images/select.png"
     title="Select Options" style="cursor: pointer" />
```

```js
//JavaScript:
function SelectOptions() {
    var popup;
    popup = window.open("popOptions.htm", "width=530,height=330");
    popup.focus();
}
```

Client window: (popup window)

```js
window.opener.document.getElementById("lblText").innerHTML = "XYZ";
```

After selecting options (on submit button click) when I try to select the text of `lblText` it returns "Select Options" instead of "XYZ" even it shows "XYZ" on screen. That means `lblText.Text` returns "Select Options" instead of "XYZ".

So my question is how can I get "XYZ" instead of it's default value?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a function in opener (main) page:

   ```
   function SetTextToLabel(newText) {
       document.getElementById("lblText").innerHTML = newText;
   };
   ```
2. Instead of

   ```
   window.opener.document.getElementById("lblText").innerHTML = "XYZ";
   ```

   call new function

   ```
   window.opener.SetTextToLabel("YourNewText");
   ```

Comment: what event you set to your "select" - tag? How you tried to get HTML after that?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't get you.

Comment: What's your JS - function to get HTML? Which events attach to "select"-tag?